# How to check if a vpn gateway is connected to a vnet through powershell script

Tags: azure, connection, azure-powershell, azure-vpn, vnet

I want to check if a vpn gateway connection is given to a vnet through a powershell command given a vnet name.

I have created 2 vnets in 2 different resource groups and enabled peering.

Answer (score 1):

You can use command in following manners

First get virtual network object from azure from following command:

Vnet_object = Get-AzVirtualNetwork -Name MyVirtualNetwork -ResourceGroupName TestResourceGroup

"Vnet_object" will be of type "PSVirtualNetworkGateway"

Pass this object in following command and you will get virtual network gateway if it is connected to that Vnet.

Get-AzVirtualNetworkGatewayVpnClientConnectionHealth
   -InputObject

Link for above command: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.network/get-azvirtualnetworkgatewayvpnclientconnectionhealth?view=azps-2.4.0

Comment: I want to check if a gateway is connected so I will not input a gateway name and Iam doing this in Resource Manager module of powershell not AZ...

Comment: same commands can be used by replacing az with AzureRM in the commands.

Answer (score 1):

If I'm not understanding you correctly, please let me know. It seems that you want to know if a VNet has gateway connected when you have enabled VNet peering.

You could use Azure PowerShell `(Get-AzVirtualNetwork  -ResourceGroupName $myrg -Name $myVnet).VirtualNetworkPeerings`, then you will check the value of parameter `AllowGatewayTransit` and `UseRemoteGateways`. One of those values is **true**, this vNet has a connecting gateway.

Additionally, the new `Az` module is used for Azure Resource Manager model, it's recommended to [migrate Azure PowerShell from AzureRM to Az](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/azure/migrate-from-azurerm-to-az?view=azps-2.4.0). If you still use the old AzureRM module, you could replace `Get-AzVirtualNetwork` with `Get-azurermVirtualNetwork`.

[image]